# Static condition of surface charges

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors, coulombs-law

[image]

We know that when charge is supplied to a conductor,they rearrange themselves on the surface thus making a static equilibrium condition. Let's suppose we have $+2e$ charge on a plane sheet conductor. Hence the charges will rearrange themselves on the surface. Now,as we see from the picture,even if they are in some rearrangement,one always exerts a coulomb force on the other and there is no other force to neutralize it. So how can these $2$ charges be static? This scenario came to my mind while learning static electricity.

Answer (score 1):

"There is no other force to neutralize it", no In fact, there is a force, If the conductor is a bounded physical object, with physical boundries, Then it will have Some metal work function associated to it, Which bounds charges, specifically electrons to the metal, Which means, there will exist a force to stop charges to move out of conductor boundry.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the force between the two charges is negligible,so acceleration is negligible and so they are static. I am not sure though.

Comment: Why is the force negligible? If the length of the sheet is small,the distance of the charges also becomes small. So force should matter in that case.